# C# - Network Programming - Verify client before allowing connection

Tags: c#, network-programming, client-server, tcplistener

I'm new to network programming as well as to stackoverflow, so I hope I won't make any bad mistakes.

I try to code a client/server application using TcpListener/TcpClient. But I don't want to accept every client trying to connect to the server.

I don't understand completely if the two parties stay connected also when the client doesn't send a request, and how it is possible to verify the client using a password or something. How could I do this?

I don't expect a tutorial but maybe a link to a good reference or youtube tutorial, I couldn't find helpful things on my research.

Thank you, fre3zr

Comment: This must be built into a higher protocol layer - TCP has no such concept. However, if you didn't wish to alter the protocol layer itself (which would still be relatively vulnerable to many other attack vectors) you could simply only listen to an interface/port secured behind an encrypted [tunneling layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) and require that clients establish such a tunnel before hand.

Comment: Yeah, rather than not accepting the client at all, you should accept it, ask for password, then either continue working or reject it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP protocol works as following: Or you accept the connection or you don't.
After accepting, you can do your checks and reject the client, if you want.

Pseudo-code:

```
Sock1.Accept()

If data then
    Store the received data in "X"
    If Password match "X" then continue, if not: KickClient()
End If
```

And yes, the client keeps connected when you finished sending your data, you must disconnect him in order to free resources.

Add code to your question, so we could help you more.